# Write XML Tag to CSV Regardless of if Another Used Tag Exists

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have an XML file containing Words and Word Definitions. Some words are connected to a base word with a definition (for example "ahh" is a base word, "ahhed" is an inflection without a definition tag).

Here is a pastebin sample of the XML I am parsing: http://pastebin.com/H3TG0Kaq

And my current code is currently as follows:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import csv

def writeToCSV(myWords):
    csvfile = open(r'xmlfile', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    fieldnames = ['hw', 'def']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    entries = myWords.getElementsByTagName("superentry")
    for entry in entries:
        try:
            word = entry.getElementsByTagName("hw")[0].childNodes[0].data
        except AttributeError:
            print(entry, entry.firstChild)
        for definition in entry.getElementsByTagName("def"):
            try:
                defValue = definition.childNodes[0].data
            except AttributeError:
                print(definition, definition.firstChild)
            writer.writerow({'hw': word, 'def': defValue})

doc = parse(r'outputfile')
myWords = doc.getElementsByTagName("dps-data")[0]

# Get get each word entry
books = myWords.getElementsByTagName("superentry")

# Print each word
writeToCSV(myWords)
```

This script allows me to bring out `<hw>` (the word) and `<def>` (the definition) from the XML file, but it doesn't print out the `<hw>` tags that don't have definitions and just skips over them.

Is there a way to print the data of a tag even if the `<def>` tag does not exist?

I'd also like to figure out how I can also print out the "base" word on those inflected words that don't have definitions (the `<xrhw>aah</xrhw>` tags)